# List combinations from a compatibility matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, networkx

I have a table in the shape of a symmetric matrix that tells me which components are compatible. Here is an example;

```
Components | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
A          |   |   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |   |   
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
B          |   |   |   |   | 1 |   | 1 | 
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
C          | 1 |   |   |   |   | 1 |   | 
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
D          | 1 |   |   |   |   | 1 | 1 | 
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
E          | 1 | 1 |   |   |   |   | 1 | 
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 
F          | 1 |   | 1 | 1 |   |   | 1 | 
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
G          |   | 1 |   | 1 | 1 | 1 |   | 
-----------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Where the 1s show what is compatible and the blanks are what is not compatible. In the actual table there are a lot more components. Currently the real table is in an excel spreadsheet but could easily be converted to csv or text for convenience.
What I need to do is create a list of possible combinations. I know there are things like `itertools` but I need it to only create a list of the compatible ones and ignore the non compatible ones. For this with a dat file I pull when I run pyomo;

```
set NODES := A B C D E F G;
param: ARCS:=
A
B
C
...
A C
A D
B E
...
A C F
BGE
...
```

I need everything listed together to be compatible together. So ACF can be together because they are all compatible with each other but not ADG because G is not compatible with A.

**Long Term Plan:**
Eventually I plan to use Pyomo to find the the best combination of components to minimize the resources needed associated with each component. Therefore in the dat file there will eventually be and additional `cost` associated with each combination.

Comment: The "all mutually compatible" can be interpreted as a fully-connected or "complete" graph of nodes.  There are tools that you can use on a set of nodes-arcs like you have to find all of the *cliques* which are the sets of fully connected nodes within a graph.  Take a look at:  https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques  and see if you can get something like that working to find your compatibility sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel(r"/path/to/file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet4",index_col=0,usecols = "A:H")
df.edge=nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
print(list(nx.enumerate_all_cliques(nx.Graph(df.edge))))
```